# Using Model-View-Presenter pattern in a MFC application

Tags: design-patterns, mfc, mvp

I work in the ui of a "quite" big MFC application.

We tried to split the application in modules to isolate the business logic but anyway there are still many places where the ui has some business logic that shouldn't be there. This business logic is difficult to test and changing a control is sometimes a real pain.
But...you all know what I mean...

Now we want to use a MVP pattern to try to really isolate the ui. I have read a lot of pappers about the pattern and seen some small examples. There is no problem with understanding the pattern but anyway I would like to go though some more complex examples (if they are from a MFC application even better) before starting.

If somebody has some good sources or knows a good book (with examples) about this pattern it would be very useful.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to revive this question. I understand what the MVP pattern is and have practiced in other platforms such as .NET and Android. I think MFC is another ideal platform for MVP. But my question I would like to ask you is how good MVP in MFC practically was?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Read Design Patterns by GOF ( Addison Wesley )

The samples are in C++

You can also go to my blog http://sujayghosh.wordpress.com and search for design patterns.

There is one example there

HTH

Sujay